# Loop through keypress Jquery (case : 1; etc..)

Tags: jquery, loops, keypress

I have a problem which is how to maintain/continue a loop if a key is pressed. I figured to animate the page with case 1 / case 2 / case 3 and case 4 but I would like to know how to continue the loop if the key is pressed again (and again...). I read about loop here but I just can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance, here is my code :

```
var counter = 0;

$(document).bind('keydown', function(e) {
    if(e.which == 37 || e.which == 39) {
        counter++;
        switch(counter) {
            case 1:
                $('#maikeximu,#dossier').stop()
                    .animate({
                        height: "toggle",
                    }, 1200, function() {
                        $('html,body').animate({
                            scrollTop: $("#maikeximu").next().offset().top
                        }, 1000);
                    });
                break;
            case 2:
                $("#gal,#dossier, #viz").stop()
                    .animate({
                        height: "toggle",
                    }, 1200, function() {
                        $('html,body').animate({
                            scrollTop: $("#gal").next().offset().top
                        }, 1000);

                    });
                break;
            case 3:
                $('#viz,#dossier').stop()
                    .animate({
                        height: "toggle",
                    }, 1200, function() {
                        $('html,body').animate({
                            scrollTop: $("#dossier").next().offset().top
                        }, 1000);
                    });
                break;
            case 4:
                $('#maikeximu, #gal,#dossier').stop()
                    .animate({
                        height: "toggle",
                    }, 1200, function() {
                        $('html,body').animate({
                            scrollTop: $("#maikeximu").offset().top
                        }, 0);
                    });
                break;
                counter = 0;
                return;
        }
    };

});
```

I hope to learn more about loops (a big problem for me) :)

Comment: your code should continue at beginning after 4 keypresses. What is it doing instead?

Comment: It looks like you are setting `counter=0` just under case 4, so every time you press a key it will only ever go into `case:1`. Is that what you are experiencing? Presumably you need to set `counter=0` before you break out of `case:4`?

Comment: @adam-marshall It's stuck. I cannot press the arrow keys again. I removed all the other function from my JS file to check if there wasn't any conflict with the code.
Edit : Thanks . I could go to the last case (4) but it was stuck after. 

I moved the counter = 0 just before the last break and it works like a charm. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lines

```
            counter = 0;
            return;
```

are within the switch statement, but not within any particular case defined there, which means they're never getting executed. This prevents the counter from resetting, which is what's stopping the animation.

Place them before the `break` ending the fourth case, thus:

```
                /* now they're here */
                counter = 0;
                return;
            break;
            /* they were here */
    }
```

and you should see it work more like what you're expecting.